# difference between ip.src!=ADDR and !ip.src==ADDR

Tags: wireshark

Say that my IP address is 192.168.1.12 and I want to see traffics that don't contain my IP address using a display filter.

The result of filter "`!ip.src==192.168.1.12 and !ip.dst==192.168.1.12`" differs from that of filter "`ip.src!=192.168.1.12 and ip.dst!=192.168.1.12`". This is so weird, can anyone explain it to me?

BTW, I've checked the wireshark's doc [6.4.7. A Common Mistake with !=](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html), and I'm sure that I'm not making the same mistakes here.

Comment: I am curious.  Can you share a sample capture file where the results of the 2 filters produce different results?  You can anonymize the capture file before posting it using an anonymization tool such as [Tracewrangler](https://www.tracewrangler.com/) if you prefer.  Only a minimal capture file that illustrates the difference is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an analogon from the analog world: There are differences between

> "show me apples that are not red"

and

> "don't show me red apples".

What would you do with green apples?

The Wiresahrk display filters work similar. If you specify `!ip.addr==192.168.1.12` you will suppress all IP packets sent from the specified IP address. But you don't suppress other packets like e.g. ARP packets.

But if you specify `ip.addr!=192.168.1.12` you get only IP packets sent from any host except the specified IP address. You will see less packets.

Since you want to check for source or destination address I use `ip.addr`. That's an abbreviation for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter traffic that don't contain IP address : "192.168.1.12" then you have below two options.

**Option: 1**

Instead of specific source and specific destination filters, you can use below filter:

!(ip.addr == 192.168.1.12)

[image]

**Option: 2**

If you want to use both source and destination filter then logical operation will be "OR". you can use below filter:

!(ip.src == 192.168.1.12 or  ip.dst == 192.168.1.12)

[image]

Comment: this is also a solution:)